# How to reset the $PATH?

Tags: node.js, npm, terminal, path

I confess, I very don't know what I'm talking about.

This morning I wanted to install Javascripting (to learn javascript) on my Mac, so I watch a video to do it:

1. I downloaded node.js and I installed it;
2. after that I opened the terminal and I type: npm install -g javascripting and here I've got some errors. I tried to search the solution but I think I created a big problem:
   Basically I modified the $PATH several times and now the situation is this.
   If I run echo PATH it displays
   /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

I wanted to clean it all so I tried to type:
brew uninstall --force node

but the terminal says:
zsh: command not found: brew

I can't do anything.

Please, someone help me :(

Comment: how did you update `$PATH` ? in a file or in shell ?.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to clear this environment variable, just do 'unset PATH'.
But, be aware that PATH is used by a shell (i.e. bash, ksh, zsh...) to look for programs in these directories. clearing it has side effects.
The 'brew' program is somewhere, to find it, you could use the following command :
find / -name 'brew' -print
It can take a little while to find it.
Either use that found path, or add the directory where that program is found to the PATH variable, as in
PATH=$PATH:/location_of_brew_program; export PATH